# YouTube Channel Design

Tags: html, css, youtube

A client has asked me to make their YouTube channel look similar this one: http://www.youtube.com/user/RayWilliamJohnson

The background is easy enough to create, but I'm not quite sure how they got that custom nav bar running along the top as well as adjusted the margin/padding to accommodate for it. Is this something that can be done easily or does it require having several million subscribers before you can use custom HTML/CSS? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [channel banner](https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&guide=30071&topic=30085&page=guide.cs&answer=1101676#Background_Image_and_Banner), and your YouTube account needs to be a Brand Channel to be able to do this. If I'm not mistaken you would have to sign up for an advertising account (which means payment of some kind). I can't access that page because I'm outside the US, but [more info here](http://www.youtube.com/advertise/brand-channel.html), presumably.